# GridLayout inflate exception

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to build a widget using a very simple `GridLayout`, but I got a InflateException:

```
Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.GridLayout
```

Is only happen in 4.0 and on 4.2 is works without problems(is there a difference between the versions?)
Somebody know something about it?

Stacktrace

```
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528): updateAppWidget couldn't find any view, 
using error view
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.GridLayout
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:1581)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHostView.updateAppWidget(AppWidgetHostView.java:289)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost.createView(AppWidgetHost.java:238)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at com.sonyericsson.home.widget.WidgetManager.getWidgetView(WidgetManager.java:142)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at com.sonyericsson.home.layer.AdapterHelper.getWidgetInfoView(AdapterHelper.java:280)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at com.sonyericsson.home.layer.desktop.DesktopAdapter.getView(DesktopAdapter.java:100)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at com.sonyericsson.paneview.PaneView.ensureItemView(PaneView.java:2343)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at com.sonyericsson.paneview.PaneView.layoutItem(PaneView.java:2294)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at com.sonyericsson.paneview.PaneView.onLayout(PaneView.java:1199)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:930)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:930)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:930)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:930)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:444)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1653)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1511)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1416)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:444)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11390)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4332)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1490)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2455)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Class not allowed to be inflated android.widget.GridLayout
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.failNotAllowed(LayoutInflater.java:618)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:558)
03-12 12:27:49.100: W/AppWidgetHostView(528):   ... 49 more
```

Layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:useDefaultMargins="true"
    android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"

    android:columnCount="4"
    >

<TextView
        android:text="Email setup"
        android:textSize="32dip"

        android:layout_columnSpan="4"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

<TextView
        android:text="You can configure email in just a few steps:"
        android:textSize="16dip"

        android:layout_columnSpan="4"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        />

<TextView
        android:text="Email address:"

        android:layout_gravity="right"
        />

<EditText
        android:ems="10"
        />

<TextView
        android:text="Password:"

        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        />

<EditText
        android:ems="8"
        />

<Space
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        />

<Button
        android:text="Next"

        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="3"
        />
```

```
    package com.path.testwidget;

 import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
 import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.widget.RemoteViews;


public class TestWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        RemoteViews rvs= new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.balance_widget);

        //update all N widgets
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {

            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, rvs);
        }

    }

 }
```

Comment: Do you mind posting the full stacktrace of the exception? And please don't prefix the title with `Android`, the tag at the bottom is more than enough.

Comment: So I include the full stacktrace and something more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**RemoteView** only allow some layout to be inflated in their content you can see the list [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout)

You can see for example that the **TableView** isn't allowed.
Your logcat message says the **GridView** isn't allowed whereas the documentation say it is.
I guess this feature is quite new and it wasn't allowed on version prior than 4.2. or 4.1.

you should probably use another layout type in your remote view.

Comment: Thanks for this guessing. I think your right also I was searching for this kind again and I found this statement that the gridlayout is avaible in Api version 16.
http://code4reference.com/2012/07/android-widget-tutorial/

Comment: 16 is 4.1,  so it may not be available on API v15, android 4.0 :/

Comment: Right so is my thinking too but I dont like the documentaion to this :(

That is with the API version not stand in the text